# How to host a local file for external http access from a C# Windows application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, iis

I've a .Net/C# Windows application which can create text/pdf files. My requirement is to make these files accessible via http links for another internal application inside my organization. The internal application only accepts http links (ftp and others are not supported).

I know this can be done manually by placing these files in an IIS server. I would like to know whether there is any easy way to do this programmatically? Once the file is created locally in my application, I should have a http link to access the file.

Comment: What do you mean "programmatically". If you place the file into a publicly available folder, it will be accessible via the webserver automatically by its filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your need correctly. You can point it out when anything wrong.

Assuming that the application create pdf files in a folder named PDFile. On IIS, you can add a site and set it physical path to PDFile folder. If you enable Directory Browsing, you can see all files when enter the url of this site in browser like this:

[image]

When you want to access these file from an external machine, just enter the url `http://serverIP:port/PDF file name` for example `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80/mycustomefile.pdf`. No need to set anything programmatically.